# Can linux containers run on Windows Server containers?

Tags: docker, windows-server, docker-for-windows, windows-server-2019

I am trying to setup a windows server for running Linux containers.

Can i run a Linux container on a Windows Server container or do i need to setup a hyper-v containers?

[Here](https://4sysops.com/archives/create-hyper-v-containers-in-windows-server-2016/) the explanation of these types of hosting containers in windows server.

Comment: Which OS is the host running?

Comment: windows server 2019

Comment: Just found out that running Linux containers on a windows server is an experimental feature. And apparently, to run then, it need the isolation provided by hyper-v containers. Read :https://serverfault.com/a/980454/255995.

Answer (score -1):

What I know: You have to setup hyper-V on your windows OS.
If you see this [link](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) you find:

> Hyper-V and Containers Windows features must be enabled.

But this manual is for Windows 10...

Anyway during installation you choose if you want using Linux containers or Windows containers.